# Background color and Column min/max options in Spyder's DataFrame viewer are disabled

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, spyder

After `pd.get_dummies` I join newly created dataframe `d_wm` to my main `df`. But now I can't enable the option `background colors` when I want to see my main `df` in the variable explorer. This option and `column min/max` aren't available. Any solutions?

Example:

```
d_wm = pd.get_dummies(df["wmg"], prefix = 'wm_gr')

df = df.join(d_wm)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check that this is a reproducible problem, i.e., this happens again after a restart?

Comment: Yes, this is repetitive problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Those options are disabled if the contents of your Dataframe are too large (too many rows, columns or data) to avoid lags when you're browsing it.

Comment: is there a way to override that?

Comment: @chitown88, no, sorry. If we allowed that then big dataframes would freeze Spyder.